# Shiny App Google Analytics API connection does not work: no JSON file found

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny

I want to access data in a Shiny App directly via Google Analytics API and now have an google OAuth 2.0 authentication issue.

My approach was the following one:

1) Created a web aplication project in my Google project and downloaded the json File. [image]

2) I added the json file to my app folder. So the structure of my app folder is the following:

- app.r
  test.json

3) Then I created a .Renviron file in the same app folder. My assumption for the error lays here, since I am not sure if I created it correctly. I created a txt file and named it .Renviron. And I inserted the following line: `GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON = "test.json"`
So now in my app folder are: app.r, test.json, and .Renviron

4) in app.R I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleAuthR)

gar_set_client(scopes = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
   gar_auth_jsUI("auth")

)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When testing with `Sys.getenv("GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON")` it always tells me, that it is empty.

And when running the app, I get the following error:

```
Error in gar_set_client(scopes = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly")) : 
  No client JSON files found
```

Does anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting a GAR_CLIENT_JSON="" in the .Renviron file as well

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm if the environment file is created properly, can you try creating your environment file this way:

1. Open up Notepad, paste in your environment variables
   [image]

   2. File > Save As...and find your local project folder, then under "Save as type" select "All Files", THEN type the File name ".Renviron"
      [image]
   3. Try again to see if the environment variable is being read.

Answer (score 0):

Try stating the full/explicit filepath in the the .Renviron file when assigning both "GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON" and "GL_AUTH"

Eg:

```
GL_AUTH="/Users/yourUser/Desktop/yourFoldername/yourFilename.json"    
GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON="/Users/yourUser/Desktop/yourFoldername/yourFilename.json"
```

Solved the error in my case.